# Манипуляция кортежа python

Tags: python

Есть кортеж, нужно заменить элементы null на 0:

```
# исходный список
listOrigin = (16.0, 493.0, 0.0),(16.0, 493.0, 'null')

# список-маска
listMask = []

# перебор элементов исходного списка
for item in listOrigin:
    if item == 'null': # Если элемент больше 0,
        listMask.append(0) # в список добавляется 1.
    else: # Если элемент равен 0,
        listMask.append(item) # в список добавляется 0.

for i in listMask:
    print(i)
```

Выводит:

```
(16.0, 493.0, 0.0)
(16.0, 493.0, 'null')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так вот (только разберитесь с нужными вам типами):

```
# исходный кортеж
tupleOrigin = (16.0, 493.0, 0.0),(16.0, 493.0, 'null')

# список-маска
listMask = [tuple(map(lambda x: x if x != 'null' else 0, t)) for t in tupleOrigin]

print(listMask)
```

Comment: `map` и `lambda` не нужны: `[tuple(0 if x == 'null' else x for x in t) for t in tupleOrigin]`

Comment: @CrazyElf да, можно и так, но я стараюсь в comprehension никогда не писать более одного `for`. Если более одного, то уже явный цикл пишу (использую numpy :))

Comment: Думаете, с map и lambda понятнее, чем с циклами? Ну не знаааю )

Comment: @CrazyElf функцию отдельно можно написать, [вот](https://repl.it/repls/FineFabulousUsernames) сравнение нескольких способов